# Laravel Subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, subdomain, laravel-6

I'm developing a project using the Laravel framework, the project is hosted on the shared host, now I would need to have a subdomain to be able to manage the "admin" section, I created my subdomain, you can use the Laravel project which is it on my main domain also on the new subdomain so that I can use the same database and the same files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same DB and files. You may use [subdomain routing](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing) to handle your subdomain URIs:

```php
Route::domain('admin.myapp.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users', function () {
        //
    });
});
```

Note: You should point your subdomain to your main domain, you may use `CNAME  *.myapp.com. myapp.com.` or config the webserver (e.g. nginx, apache, etc.) to do this.

Comment: Ok, but i need to upload some file in my subdomain directory? or i can leave it empty?

Comment: @DavideCapriglione You don't need a directory for your subdomain, you can use your main Laravel directory to handle your subdomain too.

Comment: I added the piece of code with my domain name, but when i go to the url "admin.myapp.com/users" the page return me error 404 of my hosted server

Comment: If I connect to my server via ssh and run the command "php artisan route: list" the list of Routes returns the Route "users" associated with the domain "admin.myapp.com" but when I try to reach it it returns error 404, do I need to define a DNS record or something else?